# Rxjs subscribes only once, in 1 component, not same time diff components in angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular12, angular13

Rxjs subscribes only once, in 1 component, not the same time diff components in angular 14.

**Requirements**

I am building a notification service, when any customer, submits any case, it's assigned to a support team, and I want to notify customers and the support team at the same time, or 1-2 sec duration, I am using the **WebSockets** here.

Code - `Notification.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Notification, NotificationType } from "../models/notification.model";

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  private _subject = new Subject<Notification>();
  private _idx = 0;

  constructor() { }

  getObservable(): Observable<Notification> {
    return this._subject.asObservable();
  }

  info(title: string, message: string, timeout = 3000) {
    this._subject.next(new Notification(this._idx++, NotificationType.info, title, message, timeout));
  }

  success(title: string, message: string, timeout = 3000) {
    this._subject.next(new Notification(this._idx++, NotificationType.success, title, message, timeout));
  }

  warning(title: string, message: string, timeout = 3000) {
    this._subject.next(new Notification(this._idx++, NotificationType.warning, title, message, timeout));
  }

  error(title: string, message: string, timeout = 0) {
    this._subject.next(new Notification(this._idx++, NotificationType.error, title, message, timeout));
  }

}
```

In the Notification component, I subscribe like this:

`notification.ts`

```
import { debounceTime, Subscription } from "rxjs";
private _subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private _notificationSvc: NotificationService) { }

    this._subscription = this._notificationSvc.getObservable().pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe((notification) => {
            console.log("I am notification called: -", notification);
            this._addNotification(notification)
        });
```

Websockets code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { Subject, Observable, BehaviorSubject, pipe, mergeMap } from "rxjs";
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { SharedservicesService }    from './sharedservices.service';
import { NotificationService }      from './notification.service';
@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService {
  public subject: WebSocketSubject<any>;

  currentUser: any;
  params:any;
 
  constructor(private shared: SharedservicesService, private notificationService: NotificationService) {
    this.getRequestIds();
  }

  public getRequestIds() {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if(this.currentUser) {
        const data = {
            key: this.currentUser["cognito:username"],
        }
        this.shared.getRequestIds(data).subscribe({
            next: async(response) => {
              const responseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
              this.connect(responseData.result);
            },
            error: (error) => {
              console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }
  }

  public connect(requestId) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    this.params = "?userId="+this.currentUser["cognito:username"]+"&userEmail="+this.currentUser["email"]+"&userName="+this.currentUser["custom:name"]+"&role="+this.currentUser["custom:role"]+"&requestids="+requestId
    this.subject = webSocket({
      url: environment.websocketUrlClient+""+this.params,
      deserializer: ({ data }) => {
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
          res(data);
        });
      },
      openObserver: {
        next: () => {
          console.log('connecion ok');
        },
      },
      closeObserver: {
        next: () => {
          console.log('disconnect ok');
          this.getRequestIds();
        },
      },
    });
    this.subject.subscribe();
  }

  public send(msg) {
    console.log('Send Message:', msg);
    this.subject.next(msg);
  }

  public disconnect() {
    this.subject.complete();
  }

  public receiveMessage() {
    this.subject.subscribe(
      (msg) => {
        if(msg.__zone_symbol__value != "") {
          
          const data = JSON.parse(msg.__zone_symbol__value);
          console.log('message received: ', data);

          // Problem here ---- 
          // Login 2 diff browser, Customer and support team, When send message, to support team, customer getting notification but support team are not, because support team are not in the same browser, I am using WebSocket to send the message

          if(data.sendRoomToAssignedBusinessAnalysts) { // when first Business Analyst is added
            console.log("Title:", data.title);
            console.log("Body:", data.body);
            this.notificationService.success(data.title, data.body)
            
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

There are no errors.

**Problem**

I am getting notifications for the customer, not for the support team member. Because the Rxjs subject, subscribes only once, in 1 component, not same time diff components.

Youtube link (explained about the problem): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R5dhCUC3x5s

Github repo: https://github.com/codeztech-atique/angular-websockets-testing-api

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eiqr8u

Any help would be appreciated. I am new to this. Might be something I am missing here, Let me know, what could be done.

Comment: Have you tried a `BehaviorSubject` in place of a `Subject`? It will provide a notification to any late subscribers. (The code shown above doesn't really show customer vs support team members, so I'm a bit unclear where you may have a problem. Any way you could do a short Stackblitz that demonstrates the actual issue?)

Comment: @DeborahK - I have updated the question, check my Websockets Code. BehaviorSubject won't help here, it's having the same issue. 

Any thing I am missing here? Please let me know, really need it urgently. Happy to connect.

Comment: How are you registering your services? They should have `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})` and NOT be registered in a component or module.

Comment: @DeborahK - @Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) Does not work, As you have asked, I have added Youtube link explain about the problem, also provide the GitHub code and  Stackblitz link. 

I am new to this, please help me to solve the problem

Comment: In looking at the stackbliz (and the github) there is no code that does anything in the support component? Isn't that the component that should be watching for emissions from the notification service and displaying them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very simple, there is no problem with RxJS or the subscription.

The problem is that you have `<app-notification></app-notification>` inside `customer.component.html` but inside `support.component.html` is missing.
Therefore the notification won't be displayed.

to solve your problem you have to add `<app-notification></app-notification>`to `support.component.html`.

Then you have `<app-notification></app-notification>` in both components. This works but a better solution would be to move `<app-notification></app-notification>` to `app.component.html`, so you have the component only once and it works everywhere, even if you add more pages.